# Make header file for method list for Swift file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, header-files

I have created a class (in Swift) which is a wrapper on `NSURLSession`. There are many methods in that. Now, in Swift we don't have header file. I need to have a file which lists all the methods of that class, for example we navigate to the `UITableView.h` file while we click on any default method of `UITableView` where we can all the available methods and properties for `UITableView`.

I want to do this, so any user of that class can see the list of available methods list at one place which can be used.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: For the list of methods, you can use protocol for that use your custom protocol and   make as many methods as you want. Make protocol in one class call method from other class, you get me?. So if user clicks on that he can have all methods and properties listed in the class.

Comment: This is what comments and documentation are for. Extra source code files are not recommended.

Comment: @HarjotSingh Thanks for the reply. I got direction from your answer. Can you tell me in detail how I can do it. I don't have any clue

Comment: You need to share your source code with me then, put it on some public place, i will update and send to you. Share what you have tried then only we can help.

Comment: Where may I put ?

Comment: I would recommend to Google `Protocol Oriented Programming` and you can learn what it is that you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developers can access this information in xcode anyway. Just select Generated interface in the Assistant Editor and it will show you the public interface for your class:

[image: Screenshot]

Xcode shortcut: `cmd` + `control` + `up arrow key`